# CSP header read but apparently not understood

Tags: iis, blob

So, I am trying to obtain images from an API, doing like this:

```
    fetch(callUrl, {method:'GET', 
          headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('___')}})
          .then(r => r.blob())
        .then(bl =>    {
          const imageObjectURL = URL.createObjectURL(bl);
      $('<img/>',{src:imageObjectURL})
```

On IIS, I have :

```
<system.webServer>
    <cors enabled="true">
      <add origin="_mysite_" 
          allowCredentials="true"
            maxAge="120"> 
            <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
           </add>
    </cors>
          <httpProtocol>
              <customHeaders>
              <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'  http://mysite:* blob: data:; img-src 'self' http://mysite:* data: http: https: blob:;script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'  http://mysite:*;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';frame-src *" />
              </customHeaders>
          </httpProtocol>
      
  </system.webServer>
```

Which results in a header being received:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'  http://mysite:* blob: data:; img-src 'self' http://mysite:* data: http: https: blob:;script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'  http://mysite:*;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';frame-src *
```

Nevertheless, Chrome tells me:

```
Refused to load the image 'blob:http://gdcvmas163/bfece579-fe7c-49f7-99ef-9773b592acd3' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: https:".
```

Which to me seems like it doesnt read the header at all.
What is going on/ what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below sample setting in your `web.config`. I know you want use `http://mysite:*`.

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="worker-src blob:; child-src blob: gap:; img-src 'self' blob: data:; default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:" />
```

If it works, it means that the format or writing of our CSP value value is incorrect.

Please comment all the settings about CSP, and we can create a new html for test and add `<meta>` tag for test, until it works well.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
content="
  worker-src blob:; 
  child-src blob: gap:;
  img-src 'self' blob: data:;
  default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:">
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight, which I will save for the future. This time, however, the mistake was due to my misunderstanding of which config file to edit...